# listings: control and extended chars of the IBM PC codepage 437

Tags: listings, input-encodings

This is a simplified version of [listings: emphasize Greek and have German umlaute and ß in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433245/listings-emphasize-greek-and-have-german-umlaute-and-%c3%9f-in-comments). Noone answered there, so let me simplify the question: How to use the alpha, the right arrow symbol, and the German umlaute in listings ***directly***? Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp437]{inputenc}%%% Store your file in the DOS encoding!
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[extendedchars=true]
 �  �
\end{lstlisting}
```

The symbols in the lstlisting environment are supposed to be, in their hex encoding,

(space 20) (alpha E0) (space 20) (right arrow 1A) (space 20) (a umlaut 84).

I apologize for not being able to input them into a browser verbatim.

Comment: Why are you using cp437 instead of utf8?

Answer (score 3):

You can use utf8 in listings. You only should declare the chars with literate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate={{→}{$\rightarrow$}1
                  {α} {$\alpha$}1
                  {ü} {{\"u}}1
                  }}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
dereference: Heap, Object α → α, // Rückverweis

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: pdflatex is an 8-bit application. It reads the input in 8-bit chunks. For pdflatex and listings is doesn't make a difference if the chunks are "abc" or the octects of an utf8 char.

Comment: literate clashes with emph. But imho you would get the same problems with 8bit. I would avoid to overuse emph and use delimiters und comments to get the coloring. You can also inject colors by using ` {α} {{{\lst@emphstyle{$\alpha$}}}}1` in the literate definition.